# Частые повторы в генераторе случайных чисел

Tags: java, android, случайные-числа

Пишу игру, где постоянно задействован рандом (выбор цвета, направления и стороны стрельбы противника).

И я заметил, что этот рандом очень часто повторяется (особенно если 
он произошло за маленький период времени) - т.е., например, 3 противника появляется в одном и том же месте и одного цвета подряд (и только, например, 4 уже другой).

Всего 4 разных варианта рандома для цвета и направления (получается, что 16 вариантов. И они повторяются 3-4 раза подряд очень часто. Или повторяется что-то одно, например направление).

С чем могут быть связаны частые повторы?

Comment: с тем, как вы используете рандом. Увы, хрустальный шар сегодня что-то не работает, не вижу код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно равномерное распределение, то:

```
    int size = 4;
    int[] array = new int[size];
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 500_000; i++) {
        ++array[random.nextInt(size)];
    }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Результат работы:

```
[125047, 125207, 124667, 125079]
```

стало быть теория вероятности на моём компе работает нормально. Или нужно нормальноe распределение?

Answer (score 1):

Функция Random() генерирует псевдослучайную последовательность, так что при следующем запуске программы вы можете получить ровно такую же последовательность как и в предыдущие разы. Чтобы избежать такого совпадения, обычно используют конструктор с использованием текущего времени в качестве инициирующего значения (new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())).